# Is there any updated Linkedin java sdk?

Tags: java, sdk, linkedin-api

I'm looking for Linkedin java SDK's, but all that I've found has not been updated for several months or years and I've also found that the API has suffered a major change recently through this [Linkedin post](https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition).

I've found these:

- [linkedin-j](https://github.com/nabeelmukhtar/linkedin-j), last updated four years ago, and imported from [code.google](https://code.google.com/p/linkedin-j/)
- [linkedin-j fork](https://github.com/willisju/linkedin-j), last updated a year ago
- [linkedin-java](https://github.com/skela/linkedin-java), last updated two years ago
- Another [linkedin-j](https://github.com/vijay-koppala/linkedin-j), last updated three years ago

Also, where's the updated list of REST API endpoints? Is [this page](https://developer.linkedin.com/) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the question. Being able to confirm there wasn't anything else out there yet we've open sourced https://github.com/ebx/ebx-linkedin-sdk. It's a pure Java LinkedIn API client that implements the v2 API as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/).

Disclaimer: I'm a developer of this library.

Comment: I'm interested is there any tutorial how to work with this lib?

Comment: @PeterPenzov - There is a brief "Usage and examples" section in the README. Was there something specific you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not an SDK, the official LinkedIn Java example is here:

https://github.com/linkedin/api-get-started/blob/master/java/src/com/linkedin/sample/Main.java

Comment: The last commit on this class was in 2012. It can be outdated.

Comment: @Blundell - I believe that is all for the v1 LinkedIn API. Newer functionality is only added to the v2 API (which was the reason we created the above SDK).